# How to change the URL using rewrite rule in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a page named `aircraft-gallery` and I am showing the data in this page from database its working fine.

I have another page named `aircraft-gallery-class` I am sending the data in `?id` variable and receiving that data using `GET["id"]`than I sending this data to the database for results it is also working fine.

Here is my controller in WordPress function to get id

```
public function view_air_crafts_by_class(){
        //var_dump(get_query_var('id')); //working fine
        //die();
        return $this->air_craft_model->get_air_craft_by_class($_GET['id']);
    }
```

Now my question is simple I have this URL

```
http://example.com/aircraft-gallery/aircraft-gallery-class/?id=VIP Airliner
```

and I want this URL

```
http://example.com/aircraft-gallery/VIP-Airliner
```

I am using these lines of code in my `functions.php` file to convert the URL but it's not working, I don't know why

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpa5413_query_vars' );
function wpa5413_query_vars( $query_vars )
{
    $query_vars[] = 'id';
    return $query_vars;
}

add_action( 'init', 'wpa5413_init' );
function wpa5413_init()
{
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'aircraft-gallery-class/([^/]+)/?',
        'index.php?pagename=aircraft-gallery-class&id=$matches[1]',
        'top' );
}
```

I have already tried many codes suggested by the community but it does not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am clicking saving permalinks every time I update the functions.php file. Thanks

Comment: Did you flush the rewrite rules after adding your rewrite?

Comment: I always hit the button save changes when I change my script for url purpose on Permalink Settings

Comment: It's possible that the regex is invalid, see here https://regex101.com/r/n7Tcuz/1 - although I am not entirely sure how WP handles that

Comment: I tried your reg expression and save the Permalink but it's still not working. could you please visit this url http://jetrequest.com/aircraft-gallery/aircraft-gallery-class/?id=VIP%20Airliner

Comment: Hi. Were you able to find a solution for this? If so, what is it? I'm facing the same problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpa5413_query_vars' );
function wpa5413_query_vars( $query_vars )
{
 $query_vars[] = 'id';
 return $query_vars;
}

add_action( 'init', 'wpa5413_init' );
function wpa5413_init()
{
 add_rewrite_rule(
    'aircraft-gallery-class/([^/]+)/?',
    'index.php?pagename=aircraft-gallery-class&id=$matches[1]',
    'top' );
 flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

Comment: I am finding the solution since 4 days but still facing the problem my question is simple I just want to change the url :(